# Don't create an acronym if it only appears once

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the package:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
```

and defining them as:

```
\newacronym{abs}{ABS}{Agent-Based System}
```

and calling it using:

```
\gls{abs}
```

But is there any way to not list the acronym in the `\makeglossaries` section if the acronym only appear once? If they only appear once I still want it to work normally in the document (e.g., for the text "Agent-Based System" to appear) but I don't necessarily want to create an acronym for it.

I've found this answer which gets me half way to what I want, but acronym still shows up in the `\makeglossaries`.

Comment: You could try [When showing list of acronyms using glossaries package, only show those that are mentioned at least 4 times in the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437161) and change 4 to 1 (or 3 to 0).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Hey thanks, it worked perfect