# List only multiple use acronyms in glossary while still displaying long form (short form) in text for single use

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Using the glossaries package, I would like to include only acronyms that are used more than once in the printed glossary. I came across \cgls in the documentation which solved this problem. However, acronyms that are only used once now do not display the short form along with the long form. I understand why this would be "correct" but I would like to still display the short form in the single occurrences since the acronym is often more widely recognisable.

I'm sure this is possible, I just have not managed to figure it out from the documentation so I am hoping someone can help me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{a}{AA}{Apples Apples}
\newacronym{b}{BB}{Bananas Bananas}

\makeglossaries
\glsenableentrycount % enable \cgls, \cglspl, \cGls, \cGlspl
\let\gls\cgls %cgls prints only acronyms that appear more than once to glossary

\begin{document}

\gls{a}, \gls{b}, \gls{a}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

This prints as:

```
Apples Apples (AA), Bananas Bananas, AA
Acronyms
AA Apples Apples.
```

I would like:

```
Apples Apples (AA), Bananas Bananas (BB), AA
Acronyms
AA Apples Apples.
```

Thank you for your time.

Edit: Tysm for the help. Solved for my needs with:

```
\renewcommand*{\cglsformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#1}%
  {\glsentrylong{#1}#2 (\glsentryshort{#1})}% abbreviation
  {\glsentryfirst{#1}#2}% regular term
}
```

Comment: I think the second part of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437178/106162) covers your issue (for modifying single usage only you don't need `glossaries-extra` or `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting`).

Comment: @DaiBowen thank you so much! That's done the trick. I'm sorry I didn't find this post when I looked.